# Find strings of a cell array in another cell array

Tags: string, matlab, cell-array

```
var_names = {'X1','X2'};
data_pool = {'AB\CD\X1','AB\CD\X1_A','AB\CD\X1_B','AB\CD\X2','AB\CD\X2_A','AB\CD\X2_B'};
```

The names of the variables I need the data for are X1 and X2.  The data pool has variables with similar names; '_A' and '_B' and also the strings have path names so that the strings in data_pool are always longer that those in var_names.

I need to trim down data_pool to the following:

```
var_names_new = {'AB\CD\X1','AB\CD\X2'};
```

The full paths for just X1 and X2, not the other postfixed ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
result = data_pool(endsWith(data_pool, strcat('\', var_names)));
```

This works as follows:

1. [`strcat`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcat.html) prepends `'\'` to each string in `var_names`;
2. [`endsWith`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/endswith.html) produces a logical index of strings in `data_pool` that end with any of the strings from the previous step;
3. indexing into `data_pool` yields the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check whether the current `data_pool` variable contains either `X1` or `X2` value.

```
result = {};

count = 0;
for i=1:length(data_pool)
    for j=1:length(var_names)
        new_pool = strrep(string(data_pool(i)), 'ABCD\', '');
        if contains(string(var_names(j)), new_pool)
            count = count+1;
            val = strcat('ABCD\',new_pool);
            result{1, count} = val;
        end
    end
end
```

result:

```
["ABCD\X1"]    ["ABCD\X2"]
```